# Trigger runs without errors but does not work

Tags: mysql, triggers, transactions

I created a trigger in mysql, it's no compilation error, but does nothing of what was proposed in it, is not the same as it was called.
Following code.

`DELIMITER` //

```
DROP TRIGGER BILHETAGEM_ACERTOS//

CREATE TRIGGER BILHETAGEM_ACERTOS
BEFORE INSERT ON bilhetagem FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

  SET new.bil_canal = LEFT(new.bil_canal,locate('-',new.bil_canal)-1);
      SET @plano = 0;
      SET @tarifa = 0;
      SET @placa = 0;
      SET @seq = 0;
      SET @canal = 0;
      SET @tronco = 0;
      SET @troncoplaca = 0;
      SET new.bil_gravacao = SUBSTRING(new.bil_gravacao,7);

      SELECT SUBSTRING(new.bil_canal, 1, (LOCATE('/', new.bil_canal) -1)) INTO @placa;
      IF (@placa = 'Khomp') THEN
         SET @canal = RIGHT(new.bil_canal,LENGTH(new.bil_canal) - LOCATE('/', new.bil_canal));
         SET @seq = LEFT(@canal, LOCATE('C', @canal) -1);
         IF (LOCATE('-', @canal) > 0) THEN
           SET @canal = LEFT(@canal, LOCATE('-', @canal) -1);
         END IF;
         SET @canal = RIGHT(@canal,(LENGTH(@canal) - LOCATE('C', @canal)));
         SELECT tro_codigo INTO @tronco FROM troncos_placas where tropla_placa = @seq LIMIT 1;
         SELECT tro_placa INTO @tipo FROM troncos where tro_codigo = @tronco LIMIT 1;
         SELECT tro_nome INTO @tronco_nome FROM troncos where tro_codigo = @tronco LIMIT 1;
         IF (@tipo = 'E1') THEN
            SELECT tropla_codigo INTO @troncoplaca FROM troncos_placas where tro_codigo = @tronco LIMIT 1;
         ELSE
            SELECT tro_codigo INTO @tronco FROM troncos_placas where tropla_placa = @seq and tropla_codigo = @canal LIMIT 1;
            SET @troncoplaca = @canal;
         END IF;
      ELSE
         SELECT SUBSTRING(new.bil_canal, (LOCATE('/', new.bil_canal) +1)) INTO @canal;
         SELECT tro_codigo INTO @tronco FROM troncos where tro_tipo = @placa and tro_apelido = @canal LIMIT 1;
         SET @troncoplaca = 0;
      END IF;

      IF (LOCATE('B', new.ram_codigo)) THEN 
         SET new.ram_codigo = @tronco_nome;
      END IF;
      IF (LOCATE('GATW', new.ram_codigo)) THEN 
         SET new.ram_codigo = @tronco_nome;
      END IF;

      SET new.tro_codigo = @tronco;
      SET new.tropla_codigo = @troncoplaca;

      SELECT pla_codigo INTO @plano FROM ramal where ram_codigo = new.ram_codigo LIMIT 1;

      IF @plano > 0 THEN
        IF ((LEFT(new.bil_destino,1) > 0) and (LEFT(new.bil_destino,1) <= 5)) THEN
          SELECT pla_vlrminutolocalfixo INTO @tarifa FROM planos where pla_codigo = @plano LIMIT 1;
        ELSE
          IF ((LEFT(new.bil_destino,1) > 5) and (LEFT(new.bil_destino,1) <= 9)) THEN
            SELECT pla_vlrminutolocalcelular INTO @tarifa FROM planos where pla_codigo = @plano LIMIT 1;
          ELSE
          IF (LEFT(new.bil_destino,4) <> '0800') THEN
                IF ((SUBSTRING(new.bil_destino,2,1) < 2) and (SUBSTRING(new.bil_destino,4,1) <= 5)) THEN
                  SELECT pla_vlrminutodddfixo_deestado INTO @tarifa FROM planos where pla_codigo = @plano LIMIT 1;
                ELSE
                    SELECT pla_vlrminutodddfixo_foestado INTO @tarifa FROM planos where pla_codigo = @plano LIMIT 1;
                END IF;
                END IF;
END IF;
      END IF;
   END IF;
END IF;

        SET new.pla_codigo = @plano;
        SELECT pla_tempo INTO @tempo FROM planos where pla_codigo = @plano LIMIT 1;
        SELECT pla_cadencia INTO @cadencia FROM planos where pla_codigo = @plano LIMIT 1;
        SET new.pla_tempo = @tempo;
        SET new.pla_cadencia = @cadencia;
        SET new.bil_tarifabase = @tarifa;
        SET new.bil_tarifado = 'S';
        SET @relseg = new.bil_duracao;
        SET @reldata = DATE(new.bil_dataligacao);

        IF ((LENGTH(new.bil_destino) > 4) AND (new.bil_duracao > 0) AND (new.bil_entradasaida <> 'E')) THEN
          IF (new.bil_duracao <= @tempo) THEN
            SET new.bil_vlrvenda = (@tarifa / 60) * @tempo;
          ELSE
            SET @valor = (@tarifa / 60) * @cadencia;

            SET @tmp = (new.bil_duracao - @tempo);
            SET @qtd = 1;
            WHILE @tmp > 0 DO
              SET @tmp = (@tmp - @cadencia);
              SET @qtd = @qtd + 1;
            END WHILE;

            SET new.bil_vlrvenda = @tarifa + (@valor * @qtd);
          END IF;
        END IF;

        IF (@tronco > 0) THEN
           SELECT reltro_segundos INTO @segundos from relatorio_troncos where tro_codigo = @tronco and reltro_dataligacao = @reldata limit 1;
           IF ((@segundos > 0) or (@segundos is not null)) THEN
              UPDATE relatorio_troncos SET reltro_segundos = (@segundos + @relseg) WHERE tro_codigo = @tronco and reltro_dataligacao = new.bil_dataligacao;
           ELSE
              INSERT INTO relatorio_troncos (tro_codigo, reltro_dataligacao, reltro_segundos) values (@tronco, @reldata, @relseg);
           END IF;
        END IF;
      END IF;
    END//
DELIMITER ;``
```

Comment: you need to debug it and the easiest way to do this is to add to certain points in the trigger debug info like `INSERT INTO debug_info VALUES ('updating table or something')` and after check the messages

Comment: I put insert from the first line, and even then it will not, it seems that neither enters the trigger

Comment: `SHOW TRIGGERS LIKE 'BILHETAGEM_ACERTOS'` exec it ... maybe the trigger wasn't saved.